# Is This The True Way To Implement Explicit Template Specialization Of Template Function In C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, c++20

Hi I wrote that code for my c++ course assignment, it works but I don't know if it is best way to implement explicit specialization. I am waiting for your helps, thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
T Max(const T* pArr, size_t arrSize) {
    T result{ pArr[0] };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (pArr[i] > result) result = pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
};

template<const char*> const char* Max(const const char** pArr, size_t arrSize) {
    const char* result{ pArr[0] };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << strcmp(pArr[i], result) <<std::endl;
        if (strcmp(pArr[i],result)>0) result = pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
/*
Why that didn't work?
That implementation gave us this error
Error (active)  E0493   no instance of overloaded function "Max" matches the specified type 

template<> const char* Max<const char*>(const const char** pArr, size_t arrSize) {
    const char* result{ pArr[0] };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << strcmp(pArr[i], result) << std::endl;
        if (strcmp(pArr[i], result) > 0) result = pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
*/

int main(){

    const char* carr[4]{"hello","world","RAM","ALU"};
   
    std::cout<<Max(carr,4)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't specialize, instead overload.

Comment: For code review, you can ask here at this [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The code above does not compile. Please post a [mre].

Comment: How did you test that this actually does what you intend it to do? `template<const char*> const char* Max` is not a specialization

Comment: Thank you @wohlstad I edited it. I think its could be compiled now.

Comment: Hi @UnholySheep, I tried it before  with "template<> void f(double s);"  but it didnt work

Comment: So you didn't test that this code actually works? Because as far as I can tell it won't - but you still haven't provided a full [mre]

Comment: @UnholySheep no I did test it and it is still working. I did miscopying. I will learn minimal reproducible example, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very first: You are re-inventing the wheel, there's already [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) doing nearly (returning an iterator to, not the element itself) the same!

Then to specialise a template you first need a base template and then the specialisation, for instance:

```
// the base template:
template <typename T>
void demo (T const& t)
{
    // do something with T
}

//the specialisation:
template<>
void demo<std::string>(std::string const& s) // explicit template arguments
{
    // to something specific for std::string
}

// alternatively:
template<>
void demo(std::std::string const& s) // deduced template arguments
{ }
```

You usually do so, though, only if unavoidable, e.g. some templated function calls yet another templated function with explicit template arguments and you need to adjust this other function for a specific type.

Otherwise you would rather prefer *overloading*; in your case that could look like:

```
template <typename T>
T const& max(T const arr[], size_t size) { /* ... */ }
//     ^
// note that in the general variant I'd rather return a reference to avoid
// unnecessary copies e.g. for `std::string`

// note the missing template definition!
// -> no template -> an OVERLOAD to the templates existing!
char const*  max(char const* const arr[], size_t size) { /* ... */ }
//         ^ can omit the reference, we have pointers anyway
```

Yet a totally different alternative might be providing yet another template argument that specifies the comparison, just as `std::max_element` does, e.g. like

```
template <typename T, typename Cmp = std::less<T>>
T* max(T&, T&, Cmp const& = Cmp()) { /* ... */ }
```

Instead of writing a separate function for finding the maximum you could now just provide a custom comparator:

```
char const* s[] = { "hello", "world" };
auto m = max
(
    s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s),
    [](auto x, auto y) { return strcmp(x, y) < 0; }
);
```

Now if you finally insist on the specialisation it would look like this:

```
template <typename T
T const& max(T const arr[], size_t size) { /* ... */ }

// here with deduced template arguments:
template<>
char const*& max(char const* const arr[], size_t size) { /* ... */ }
//         ^
// now we need the reference (if you actually add as I proposed)
// to remain compatible with the base template
```

Comment: You're missing a `const` it has to be `char const* const arr[]`

Comment: @UnholySheep Indeed, somehow overlooked that in the west-consting variant ;) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions @Aconcaqua. I will note the best-practice implementation of finding maximum of an array with custom comparer but I am doing it for learning templates in cpp that's why I did it in that way

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work because I made mistake when writing parameter type and type specifiers. I realize to that I wrote in wrong order

```
template<> const char* Max<const char*>(const const char** pArr, size_t arrSize) {
    const char* result{ pArr[0] };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << strcmp(pArr[i], result) << std::endl;
        if (strcmp(pArr[i], result) > 0) result = pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the correct version of my Explicit Template Specialization

```
template<> const char* Max<const char*>(const  char* const* pArr, size_t arrSize) {
    const char* result{ pArr[0] };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << strcmp(pArr[i], result) << std::endl;
        if (strcmp(pArr[i], result) > 0) result = pArr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Apart from that the code in the question placed the template arguments at the wrong place as well: `template<const char*> const char* Max(...` ;)

Comment: By the way, you get more consistent code by 'east-consting' (placing `const` always to the right, thus at the east of the object) consistently – in your variant ('west-consting') you one time need to place `const` to the left, but yet another time to the right...